# Examples of Mathematical Models

Tags: mathematical-modeling

For an assignment at my uni I have to investigate a mathematical model in detail and analyse the math within it, but currently I'm having a very hard time finding what model I want to do, and I can't find a large list of examples of models and was wondering if anyone could give me a good few examples?

Comment: Have you asked your TA?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~madjl/course_text.pdf